# What are these ~100 extra questions?

Tags: bug, questions, search, caching

There is a discrepancy between

[All Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions): 19,821,501 questions

and

[Search Results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion): Results found Search options questions only (is:question): 19,821,596 results

moments apart.  What/Why?  (I am just curious.)  More importantly: Is this a bug?

Comment: Did you try caching? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69164/does-stack-exchange-use-caching-and-if-so-how and https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/178597/158100

Comment: https://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: Beyond caching, these two pages simply do not query the same data sources.

Comment: No repro: I see 19,821,593 questions on All Questions. I do see a different number on the search results, but that's because I'm a member of a Team.

Comment: @Cody, hey, it's been a while since we've done this ;) I'm a member of no team and there is a discrepancy for me (all questions: 19,821,581 | search results: 19,821,666).

Comment: @rene, I just forcibly reloaded both; the discrepancy persists.

Comment: @greg, they meant server-side caching.

Comment: @greg-tumolo it is not client-side caching. The webserver keeps a cached version so it doesn't have to query the database on every page load.

Comment: Ah!  Thanks, rene and Frédéric Hamidi.

Comment: Specially the Elastic search is known to lag behind. Questions get added and deleted faster then Elastic gets updated.

Comment: @Frédéric I read [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399356/what-are-these-100-extra-questions#comment782136_399356) that they don't query the same data sources. ;-)